# How to make Windows 10 File Explorer preview pane black background and grey text?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, preview-pane

Windows 10 File Explorer has preview pane (hotkey to turn it on/off is Alt + P).

It can be used to display content of text file and the default background color for it is white and the default text color for it is black.

I'm using Windows 10 Dark mode at the moment, so the file explorer is in dark mode too.

How can I make the File Explorer preview pane black background and grey text?

Comment: You can try modifying the corresponding registry entries for the Explorer GUI (`HKCU\Control Panel\Colors`), however Microsoft made several changes to what is, and is not, modifiable within Explorer in Windows 10.  You can try [WindowBlinds](https://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/), but the changes Microsoft made prevented certain aspects of Explorer from being modified in Win10 that were previously modifiable in Windows <=8.1.